# Type mismatch: inferred type is (Mutable)Iterable<User!>! but List<User> was expected

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin

I have a problem when I want to implement @GetMapping in UserController.kt

```
package com.testao.andikaputra.crudcustomer.controller

import com.testao.andikaputra.crudcustomer.repository.UserRepo
import com.testao.andikaputra.crudcustomer.model.User
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import java.util.*
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")

class UserController(private val userRepo: UserRepo){
 
  @GetMapping("/users")
  fun getAllUser(): List<User> =
  userRepo.findAll()
}
```

The userRepo.findAll() shows an error "Type mismatch: inferred type is (Mutable)Iterable<User!>! but List was expected"

Here is my User.kt

```
package com.testao.andikaputra.crudcustomer.model
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
         @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long=0,
         val NamaPertama: String,
         val NamaKeluarga: String,
         val email: String
)
```

Here is my UserRepo.kt

```
package com.testao.andikaputra.crudcustomer.repository

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import com.testao.andikaputra.crudcustomer.model.User
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

@Repository
interface UserRepo : JpaRepository<User, String>
```

Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove `import java.util.*`  you should be using kotlin's `List`

Comment: @Andika Putra Agustian, have you tried @ sidgate suggestion? Did it work?